# Assimp Command Line to Convert OBJ file to SLT

Tags: command-line, 3d, 3dsmax, assimp

I need to be able to import OBJ file to SLT using Assimp.

I found this where someone was able to export OBJ file to JSON.

```
    assimp2json.exe assimp2json seaknight.obj seaknight.json
```

([is it possible to run assimp commandline tool with the php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930225/is-it-possible-to-run-assimp-commandline-tool-with-the-php))

I need able to do the same like this:

```
  assimp darkwader.obj drakwader.slt
```

So, I can print in my 3d printer.

Here is the complete list of imported and exported 3D file formats:
https://github.com/assimp/assimp

Answer (score 3):

Try `assimp export darkwader.obj drakwader.slt`

Comment: @Dima_Stebaev  how do compile this code?  Which folder is assimp applications located?

Comment: @user914425 do you use Linux or Windows?

Comment: @Dima_Stebaev I have both a mac OSX 10.11 and Windows 7 machines.  I am trying to get it compiled.   After that I would like to get it working on Linux Centos.

Comment: @user914425 you can download Windows binaries from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/assimp/files/assimp-3.1/
But if you wanted to use assimp on Linux you have to build it for Linux.
`git clone https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git`
`cd assimp`
`cmake CMakeLists.txt -G 'Unix Makefiles'`
`make`
Binary file will be located in the `bin/` folder.